# Play2 - adding scala nature couses errors

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0

i installed Play2 plugin for eclipse, and whem I am trying to add scala nature to project i receive error message -> "The import views.html.index cannot be resolved". I was trying to recompile, clean, refresh, rebuild it, but nothing works. If I remove scala nature from project everything works fine. Maybe you have some ideas how i can fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix but a workaround for this Scala + Eclipse problem is creating a 2nd project for only editing the template files.

- run 'activator clean eclipse'
- remove Scala nature from main project
- create new Scala project in Eclipse (File -> New -> Project -> Scala Wizards -> Scala Project
  --> use default settings
  --> don't switch to Scala view
- in a Linux shell remove all files and folders from the new project except for .project and .settings
- create a folder 'app' (or the root Java source folder in the main project
- create a symling from your main project views folder into the new projects app folder named 'views'
- create a symlink from the main project bin folder to the new project, named 'bin'
- create a symlink from .classpath to the new project
- in Eclipse refresh the project
- edit new projects properties
  --> Java Build Path -> Source, check if the app folder is the source folder